# WCF: Protocol Exception - 400 Bad Request

Tags: wcf, web-config, image-uploading, mtom

I'm developing a web site that can upload and download pictures. Download works fine, there aren't issue, but in the meanwhile the upload has a bad issue with pics bigger than 16 KB, telling me: "Protocol Exception: Error 400 Bad Request".

That is telling me that I've to increase the size of MaxArrayLength in XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas, but I've already did that.

I'll show you my webConfig:

Client:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceImage" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="4194304" maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="4194304" maxArrayLength="4194304"
            maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

WCF:

```
 <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceImage" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="4194304" maxArrayLength="4194304"
          maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Any idea?

Edit: I can upload file until they are tiny than 16KB, and I cannot found where I have to handle that value to increase.

---

Sounds like for huge file, wcf has got some issue, so I have to change the "encodeMessage" to MTOM and move from BasicHttpBindings to wsHttpBindings.
By the way that is not working yet, new issues appears on my code. Damn it.

Client WebConfig:

```
<bindings>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="4194304"
        maxArrayLength="4194304" maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Service WebConfig:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"

             maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <!--messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" maxBufferSize="4194304" transferMode="Buffered" -->
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="4194304"
        maxArrayLength="4194304" maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>
  <service  name="WcfService.FileService" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Is your configuration used for the service endpoint?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: I think that it is what are you asking:

<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:XXXXX/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceImage" contract="WCFImages.IServiceImage"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceImage" />
    </client>

Like I said, for small images that works fine. Bigger than 2KB isn't.

Comment: What's the value of `maxRequestLength` in your web.config?

Comment: maxRequestLength is setted at 4194304.
By the way I found that wcf has some issue with huge data file, so I change the "messageEncoding" to MTOM. Now I've got some new issue eheh

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a scenario where you'd want to use Streaming services instead of Buffered.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Coincidentally something I am wrestling with implementing myself.